# convert epoch time into normal datetime format in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, epoch

Well, I am going to convert the epoch into a normal datetime in oracle sqldeveloper, I wrote the below code, but it says "missing expression"
My code:

```
SELECT to_date(CreationDate, 'yyyymmdd','nls_calendar=persian')+ EpochDate/24/60/60
from table1
```

My table1:

| ID | EpochDate |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 16811048 |
| 101 | 16810904 |
| 102 | 12924715 |
| 103 | 15667117 |

I don not know what is wrong!

Comment: Please provide reproducible example: post table definition as DDL, sample data as `insert`s. Currently your table has no `EpochDate` column

Comment: CreationDate column is supposed to be a EpochDate, actually I am new in oracle, I do not know what is wrong with my code!

Comment: I edited my column, but still it did not work

Comment: Of course it doesn't work because now it has no `CreationDate` column. Steps are very simple: 1) DDL of the table (`create table your_table ( creationdate <datatype>, epochdate <datatype> )`). 2) `insert into your_table values (...)`

Comment: You don't have any CreationDate column. How did you use it?! Add your sample data and your desired result separately. (two different tables and not as image)

Comment: What is the datatype of CreationDate and EpochDate in database?

Comment: You rename column names back and forth, but it obviously cannot help: you use two columns in your query, but the table has only one with matching name.

Answer (score 1):

If the CreationDate is a `Date` and EpochDate is a `Varchar` you can try this:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(CreationDate, 'yyyymmdd','nls_calendar=persian'),'yyyymmdd') +
       EpochDate/24/60/60 as newDate
from table1
```

or:

```
select to_date(to_char(CreationDate, 'yyyymmdd','nls_calendar=persian'),'yyyymmdd') +
       numtodsinterval(EpochDate,'SECOND') as newDate
 from dual
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this conversion `to_date(to_char(CreationDate, 'yyyymmdd','nls_calendar=persian'),'yyyymmdd')`?

Comment: She needs to convert her CreationDate to persian calender format.

Comment: I mean that the date is the same, it has no format, calendar is about date representation at display time. The only possible reason is when they have initially saved the persian date as a general date, but it is hard to tell because `to_date(reationDate, 'yyyymmdd','nls_calendar=persian')` is either about `varchar2` or rely on default nls_settings. Anyway, initial statement should not throw *missing expression* as it is about the same (just without additional `to_char`). That's why sample data is required

Comment: No. The date is not the same. Today in our calender  is 15.09.2021 and in their is 24.06.1400.

Comment: The date is. Its display is different, but the value in the column of type `date` should be the same

Comment: True. I think she wants to show the date in Persian. Actually she can convert after addition.

Answer (score 0):

Let's show you how in an example

Demo data

```
SQL> create table c1 ( id number generated always as identity, date_test date) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into c1 ( date_test ) values ( sysdate ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into c1 ( date_test ) values ( sysdate-365 ) ;

1 row created. 

SQL> insert into c1 ( date_test ) values ( sysdate-4000 ) ;

1 row created. 

SQL> insert into c1 ( date_test ) values ( sysdate-7200 ) ;
    
1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.
```

Now, let's add a column called `epoch`, and a small function to make easier to update the column.

```
SQL> alter table c1 add epoch number ;

Table altered.

SQL> create or replace function date_to_unix_ts( PDate in date ) return number is
   l_unix_ts number;
begin
   l_unix_ts := ( PDate - date '1970-01-01' ) * 60 * 60 * 24;
   return l_unix_ts;
end; 
/

Function created
```

We update the column epoch with the real epoch date based on the timestamp field

```
SQL> update c1 set epoch=date_to_unix_ts (date_test) ;

4 rows updated.

SQL> select * from c1 ;

        ID DATE_TEST                                            EPOCH
---------- ---------------------------------------- -----------------
         1 2021-09-15 12:25:25                             1631708725
         2 2020-09-15 12:25:25                             1600172725
         3 2010-10-03 12:25:25                             1286108725
         4 2001-12-29 12:25:26                             1009628726


SQL> select to_char(to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval(EPOCH,'SECOND'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from c1 ;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('19
-------------------
2021-09-15 12:25:25
2020-09-15 12:25:25
2010-10-03 12:25:25
2001-12-29 12:25:26
```